# Swift 4, how to remove two nth charterers from sentence, and start counting each letter in sentence from 1 instead of 0

Tags: swift

I've come outwith this code to remove two charahcters from sentence, however I was wondering how to start counting sentence from 1 when removing characters.

```
Examplre user enters in each textfield as following:
textfield.text: Hi, thankyou 
inputlabelOne.text: 2
inputLabelTwo.text: 5
```

My code:

```
var numberOne = Int (InputLabelOne.text)!
var numberTwo =  Int (InputLabelTwo.text)!
var text   =  textfield.text!
var num1 = numberOne
var num2 = numberTwo                 

if let oneIndex = text.index ((text.startIndex), offsetBy: 
              num1, limetedBy:(text.endIndex)) , 
              let twoIndex = text.index ((text.startIndex), offsetBy: num2, 
              limetedBy:(text.endIndex))  {

    text.remove(at: oneIndex)
    text.remove(at: twoIndex)
    outputLabel.Text = "sentence with removed letters: \(text)"       
}
```

Comment: What is the question here other than counting from 1, do you have an issue with the code posted?

Comment: so the code starts counting form 0, so if user inputs 2 and 3, it will remove 3 and 4th letters. i want it to remove what the user inputs. Thanks

Comment: Then subtract one from the given offsets ...

Comment: I did (num1 - 1) and (num2 - 1) however only 1 of them worked and the other stayed counting from 0

Comment: And note that the first removal *modifies* the string ... what does that mean for the second removal?

Comment: they both modify the string but  when user enters 2 and than enters 3, only 2 gets removed correctly while 3 gets the 4th removed

Comment: If you start with "1234" and remove the second character then you have "134". Now you remove the third character from "134". Now you have ...?

Comment: they both are removed at same time from "1234",so remove second character  and third character now I have: 13. So the second character was removed but the other didn't remove the third it removed the fourth.

Comment: No, they are not removed “at the same time.” `text.remove(at: oneIndex)` removes the "2" from "1234" so that the text becomes "134". Then `text.remove(at: twoIndex)` removes the "4" from the text so that it becomes "13".

Comment: Thanks, that what i mean

Comment: See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3018532-remove:  All the elements following i **are moved** to close the gap. .... Calling this method **invalidates any existing indices** for use with this string.

Comment: than how do I remove two letters at the same time from the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to get first index of the string

```
let startIndex = string.startIndex
```

Next, you need to get String.Index of the character at first position

```
let index1 = string.index(startIndex, offsetBy: num1 - 1)
```

I type minus one because first character has 0 index

Next, you can remove this character

```
str.remove(at: index1)
```

Same for the second character

```
let offset = num1 > num2 ? 1 : 2
let index2 = string.index(startIndex, offsetBy: num2 - offset)
str.remove(at: index2)
```

If num1 is less than num2 then offset value is 2 because we have already removed one character.
If num1 is greater than num2 then offset value is 1 as for num1.

Comment: But when user inputs 1 (offsetBy: num2 - 2)  it does not give them the first number

Comment: I forgot about this case

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the *mutating while iterating* mistake you have to remove the characters **backwards** starting at the highest index.

To get 1-based indices just subtract 1 from the offset respectively

```
var text = "Hi, thankyou"
let inputLabelOne = 2
let inputLabelTwo = 5

if let oneIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: inputLabelOne - 1, limitedBy: text.endIndex),
    let twoIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: inputLabelTwo - 1, limitedBy: text.endIndex) {
    text.remove(at: twoIndex)
    text.remove(at: oneIndex)
}

print(text) // H, hankyou
```

or as function

```
func remove(at indices: [Int], from text: inout String) {
    let sortedIndices = indices.sorted(by: >)
    for index in sortedIndices {
        if let anIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: index - 1, limitedBy: text.endIndex) {
            text.remove(at: anIndex)
        }
    }
}

remove(at: [inputLabelOne, inputLabelTwo], from: &text)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `remove(at:)` invalidates **all** indices, not only the “larger” ones. So this may work, but it is not guaranteed according to the documentation.